# Does $2y^2=4+17x^4$ have solutions in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Does $2y^2=4+17x^4$ have solutions in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$ ?
My try is the following, is this correct ?

Look at $2$ adic valuation $v$ of $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$ on both side.

$v(2y^2)=1+2v(y)$,

$v(4+17x^4)=min\{2,4v(x)\}$(because $2=v(4)\neq v(17x^4)=4v(x)$).

But $1+2v(y)$ and $min\{2,4v(x)\}$ never equals because $v$ is discrete valuation.

Thus $2y^2=4+17x^4$ does not have solution in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$$■$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is a good attempt, but there is a step missing. You claim that $1+\nu(y)$ cannot be equal to $2$ or $4\nu(x)$ because you think of $\nu$ as taking integral values. This is not  necessarily true as we are in an *extension* of $\mathbb{Q}_2$. 

If we instead were in $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{-3})$, then your analysis of $x^2+3$ would fail. Indeed, following your logic, since this equation has a solution only if the valuation is $\infty$, it would require $\nu_3(3)=1$ and $\nu_3(x^2)=2\nu_3(x)$ to be equal, which is impossible. But it *is* possible, indeed $\nu_3(\sqrt{-3})=\frac12$.

Comment: One way to remedy this is to argue that the extension is unramified, as this is implies the extension of $\nu_2$ is still integral. You can do this over $\mathbb{Q}$ first and then use the properties of number field completion.

Comment: Ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is $R=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$, $R/(2)\cong \Bbb{F}_4$, thus $2$ inerts in extensionn $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})/\Bbb{Q}$. Ramification degree at $2$ is equal to the ramification index of local version extension $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})/\Bbb{Q}_2$,which is $1$. Thus ramification index of  $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})/\Bbb{Q}_2$ is $1$. Is this correct ?

Comment: In your fist comment, what is an equation you are thinking ? Where $x^2+3$ came from ?

Comment: Yes, this is a good attempt. You do need to add a bit about possible ramification, but if you know what unramified extensions look like, you'll be fine.

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction The equation $x^2+3$ was just an example, showing that your approach isn't correct unless you add a further argument. 

And yes, I love your argument that the extension is unramified! Now, the extension of the valuation is "unramified" as well, i.e. it is still integral. This follows immediately for how you define $\nu_2$ on $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$. And then your original argument works.