# Why's $v_L (x)=\frac{1}{n}v_K(N_{L/K}(x))$ integer for unramified local field extension $L/K$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

If $K$ is a local field and $L/K$ is a finite extension, then the valuation $v_K$ can be extended uniquely to a valuation $v_L$ of $L$ such that $v_L$ restricted to $K$ is equal to $v_K$. This is one of the fundamental theorems about local fields. If $L/K$ is finite, $v_L$ is given by
$$v_L (x)=\frac{1}{n}v_K(N_{L/K}(x)),$$
for every $x\in L$, where $n=[L:K]$ and $N_{L/K}$ is the norm.

This is not discrete valuation in general.
For example, $v_L(\sqrt{-3})=\frac{1}{2}ord_3(3)=\frac{1}{2}$ in an extension $L=\Bbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{-3})/K=\Bbb{Q}_3$.

But when **$L/K$ is unratified**(Uniformizer does not change under field extension), why is $v_L$ discrete valuation(In other word, why $v_L(x)\in \Bbb{Z}$ ?)

Background: Sorry to ask a basic question about extension of valuation, but this question's comments made me realize that I didn't understand the material and this is separated one from the linked page.

[Does $2y^2=4+17x^4$ have solutions in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708077/does-2y2-417x4-have-solutions-in-bbbq-2-sqrt-3),

Comment: Is your example correct? 
$N_{L/K}(\sqrt{-3})=9$ so that $v_L(\sqrt{-3})=\tfrac{1}{2}v_3(9)=1$. This might be able to help you: when $L/K$ is unramified, the ramification indices $e_{L/K}=1$ and $v_L(x)=v_K(x)$ for all $x \in K$, that is, a uniformizer of $K$ is also a uniformizer for $L$.

Comment: @Adler Marques. I think $N_{L/K}(\sqrt{-3})=\sqrt{-3}×(-\sqrt{-3})=3$.

Comment: @Adler Marques. Could you tell me why $v_L(x)=v_K(x)$ ? I understand uniformizer does not change under unratified extension, but why that implies $v_L(x)=v_K(x)$ ?

Comment: "This is not discrete valuation in general."  That's wrong: the function $v_L$ is a discrete valuation since its values are the discrete group $(1/e)\mathbf Z$, where $e$ is the ramification index of $L/K$.

Comment: @KCd  Thank you very much. Could you tell me why value group is $\frac{1}{e} \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: That is in many books on $p$-adic analysis: p. 158 in Gouvea, p. 66 in Koblitz, and p. 98 in Robert.  You chose to normalize $v_K(K^\times)$ to be $\mathbf Z$, but without making any normalization you could say $e(L/K) = [|L^\times|:|K^\times|]$.

Comment: Sorry, I did it thinking about in $3i$.

Comment: The first thing you should write here is what definition of "unramified" you are using. Because in some sense, what you are asking is almost the definition.

Comment: By the way, $\mathbb Q$ is not a local field, so your example makes no sense to begin with. It would be an example if you consider that extension e.g. for $K=\mathbb Q_3$, the $3$-adics.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg. Thank you for your correction, I edited my question. If I adapt the definition of unratified extension as 'uniformizer does not change by extensio', why valuation is integer ?

Comment: It's "unra**m**ified". And well, what is a uniformizer? An element with minimal positive valuation? So if a uniformizer for $K$ is also one for $L$ ...